# How to modernize SharePoint 2019 on prem

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, modern-experience, 2019, modern-team-site

I am working on SharePoint 2019 on premises environment. We have upgraded all the way from 2010, 2013 and SharePoint 2016, and now we are on 2019.

I have searched a lot on how to modernize our web applications and site collections, but I am struggling to find anything related to SharePoint 2019 with regards to modernization.

For instance we can use `GoToModern();` in browser console on Office 365, and also have PowerShell commands to modernize:

```
ConvertToPnPClientSidePage
```

Do we have anything like that for SharePoint 2019 on premises? Any other ideas on how we can modernize our existing site collections ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design, we can't convert classic site to modern site in SharePoint 2019.

There is no such powershell available for SharePoint server 2019, only available for SharePoint online.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Julie_MSFT